# Jersey's EventSource blocks until first data chunk was receiveid

Tags: java, jersey

I am using Jersey to connect to an server SSE channel (also implemented by using Jersey).

Client code:

```
...
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
EventSource client2es = new EventSource(target)
...
```

My problem is that `new EventSource(target)` blocks until the server sents the first chunk of data. The Jersey EventSource implementation invokes `awaitFirstContact()` as soon as `EventSource.open` is called.

Is there any reason why the first contact must be awaited? How to connect to an event source without blocking the client until the server sent the first data chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of EventSource, the `awaitFirstContact()` doesn't seem necessary in `open` method. I think there definitely should have been `open`  method without blocking, because other processing is done asynchronizely. So I think you have to workaround it.
There is a second parameter in `EventSource` constructor - `boolean open`. You can pass `false` there, so the eventsource will not be opened, than create new thread to open eventsource there.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebTarget target = null;//...
        EventSource es = openAsynchronizely(target);

        es.register(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
                ///...
            }
        });
    }

    static EventSource openAsynchronizely(WebTarget target) {
        EventSource eventSource = new EventSource(target, false);
        new OpenThread(eventSource).start();
        return eventSource;
    }

    static class OpenThread extends Thread {
        private final EventSource eventSource;

        public OpenThread(EventSource eventSource) {
            this.eventSource = eventSource;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            eventSource.open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Running a dedicated Thread just for opening a single event source is a waste of ressources. This can also be achived by using `EventSource.target(target).build()` without using the overloaded version of the constructor.

Comment: It's not like you have other choice to run async-ly aside from patching the library... As for creation - whatever you prefer...